# Maximize a linear equation with a modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can i maximize the function of the type (ax + b) % c where a, b, c are constants and are given while x is a integer variable ?

I'm not getting any idea how to start solving such problems.

Comment: You say $a,b,c$ are constants.  Are they constant *integers*?

Comment: Use the distribuitive property of the modular operator. Anyway if $x$ is not bounded you'll find no maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which representatives you are using  modulo $c$.  If oyu are choosing the integers $[0,c-1]$, then the following works.

The largest residue we can generate is $ax+b = c-k$ for some integer $k>0$.  We have $ax = c-b-k$, so for $x$ to be an integer, $a$ divides $c-b-k$.  So let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $a$ divides $c-b-k$.  Then $c-k$ is the maximum attained value.

To get a formula, we want $c-b-k \cong 0 \pmod{a}$, so $k \cong c-b \pmod{a}$.  (We must take $k=a$ if we would have taken $k=0$.)  Then, in your notation, `c-((c-b)%a?(c-b)%a:a)` (or `if(0 != (c-b)%a) ) {max = c-((c-b)%a);} else {max=c-a;}`, if you don't recognize the ternary operator) is the maximum value attained.  (Note that some languages do dumb things when `%` has negative argument(s), so you may need to make adjustments to correct for language or library deficiencies.)