# Maximum Remainder of (a*x)%c

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, optimization, modular-arithmetic

`a` and `c` are Integer constants, where `a`<`c`.

`x` belongs to the set of Natural Numbers.

How to maximize the result of `(a*x)%c`?

[Over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814115/maximize-a-linear-equation-with-a-modulo) if we assume that `b=0` then the solution given in the answer doesn't work.

Suggested Answer for maximization of `(ax +b)%c`:-

`if(0 != (c-b)%a) ) {max = c-((c-b)%a);} else {max=c-a;}`

Suppose `a=15`,`c=21` and `b=0` then according to this post the answer should be:-

`max = 21-((21-0)%15)`

`max = 21-(21%15)`

`max=21-6`

`max=15`

but for `x=4` we get the result `ax%b` as `15*4 % 21` which is `60%21` or `18`.

Comment: I'm sure we just had this question a few days ago, but I can't find it. The maximum value is $c-\gcd(a,c)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177986/construct-an-algorithm-to-find-the-multiple-of-a-such-that-ab-is-maximized and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177895/what-is-maximum-value-of-a-b-mod-c-where-a-and-c-are-known